# c++ separate files?

Tags: c++, file

My question is, when you compile your c++ program, why is it all put into one exe file? The file could become to large. Would you use dll libraries to shrink the size, or are there other files you can make? I just want to know how to make a program that uses separate files to run.

(EDIT) I just don't want it all in a single file. Files could become too large eventually for the computer to handle it, right? There must be a way to separate the files. Like in java, everything is in a class file, which just seems easier and more efficient. Some drives like FAT32 can't have a file bigger than 4 gigabytes, so they need a more broken down program. I looked at my game called portal, its exe is 100KB and it has about 100 dll files!

Comment: Why would a single executable be "too large"? Without storing resources (e.g. images/media), that's quite hard to do on modern non-embedded systems .. use dynamic linking for *logical* boundaries: a large component of the application *designed* as a library, an existing 3rd party library, modules of a plugin system, etc.

Comment: I no longer worry about exe size since its miniscule compared to the size of the storage or ram. Back in the 1990s I did worry about these things however.

Comment: "Files could become too large eventually for the computer to handle it, right" - That is highly unlikely that you will create a 2GB executable for usage on a 32 bit platform.

Comment: Responsiveness can be improved by keeping the exe small and delay-loading dlls.  That way the application quickly brings the user to a useful place, and the time to load additional dlls is delayed until it is required.

Comment: @NateHekman Sure, if loading off of a [Jaz drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaz_drive). Modern - or, any recent - HDD's are *very fast* at sequential reads. Respectable SSDs are even faster. And, if the DLL has to be loaded *anyway* (i.e. not used as an optional plugin module) ..

Comment: Addressing the Portal comment in the question, there are other reasons for splitting your code into multiple DLLs, but reducing executable size usually isn't one of them.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, yes. You absolutely can split your program into separate DLL files if you'd like.

I've seen some developers compile utility functions into a separate common DLL files which can be included in other projects as references. This way its objects and methods can be be called from it.

In hindsight, compiled code is relatively small. Binary data is really what consumes the most space: videos, images, models, sounds, etc. Although it is possible and common for smaller programs to pack these resources directly into the executable, it generally isn't a good idea for many obvious reasons.

Finally, large executables aren't a huge problem with today's technology. For smaller programs, I wouldn't sweat it. It's more about the design development the larger the project gets.

Answer (score 2):

Too large for what?  If it was due to storage space restrictions, splitting it into multiple files wouldn't buy you anything.  Unless you are somehow overflowing the maximum size for a file on a platform (like a 2GB limit on some 32-bit platforms), which seems very unlikely, you are probably worrying about a non-issue.

You can reduce the size of the generated executable by turning off debug options in the compiler, "stripping" it on various platforms, setting optimization settings to optimize for code size rather than execution speed, etc.

Comment: It's even "hard" to make a 2MB executable (without resources or statically linking external/runtime libraries), much less to come close to 2GB .. compiler output is very dense on the space spectrum and it takes much longer to author code than record a video or create a large image.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the original question, which is asking how to split an exe into multiple files.

Comment: The question is a misunderstanding about exe files being too big, not how to split them into many dll's IMO.. which in fact would make it take longer to load and more disk space due to cluster size rounding..

Comment: The original question didn't really make much sense, and still doesn't after he edited it.  It's extremely unlikely the executable will ever be too large.  Data files can often do this, but executables rarely do, and haven't since 8-bit days really.

Comment: @paulm, I suspect you are right, but that should be clarified in the comments, not in an answer, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The way to split an exe into several files (on Windows) is, as the OP suggested, to use dlls.

The commenters are correct that this will not actually take any less space on disk, nor save any memory, but there are other reasons to split an application into multiple files.  For example, to share code (a single dll can be used by several applications), or to help an application load more quickly (only load the dll when it is actually needed).